# Error while starting JBOSS Server?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I am facing a strange problem while i am starting my JBOSS Server(without any application deployed to it). Below is my application stacktrace.

> 19:36:33,178 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version
>   1.1.2.GA-redhat-1 19:36:33,443 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA-redhat-1 19:36:33,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) starting 19:36:33,880 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>     at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:270)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:156)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0] Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
>   Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:1.5}server'    at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>     ... 3 more
>
> 19:36:33,880 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has
>   failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for
>   details. 19:36:33,881 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss EAP
>   6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) stopped in 8ms

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with your configuration, at row 3, column 1.

Please check your standalone.xml.

Maybe you are missing `<extensions>...</extensions>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check at row 3 col 1 in your config file (standalone.xml).
ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]